# Parsing code syntax using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse simple code syntax,

```
abc or def
```

and

```
def and abc or ghi
```

I am using this simple regex, unfortunately it does not identify and / or logical operators.

```
(((\s)*(abc|def|ghi)(\s)*)(\s(and|or)\s((\s)*(abc|def|ghi)(\s)*))*)+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend having a look at [an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/hD1gS5/1) to learn more and try to fix your regex.

Comment: Also, it's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's updated regex that works fine with this solution,

```
(((abc|def|ghi))((\s*(and|or)\s*)((abc|def|ghi)))*)+
```

The issue was with greedy search for \s* with group 2.